# How can I use ddply with varying .variables?

Tags: r, plyr

I use ddply to summarize some `data.frame`by various categories, like this:

```
# with both group and size being factors / categorical
split.df <- ddply(mydata,.(group,size),summarize,
                  sumGroupSize = sum(someValue))
```

This works smoothly, but often I like to calculate ratios which implies that I need to divide by the group's total. How can I calculate such a total within the same `ddply` call?

Let's say I'd like to have the share of observations in group A that are in size class 1. Obviously I have to calculate the sum of all observations in size class 1 first. 
Sure I could do this with two ddply calls, but using all one call would be more comfortable. Is there a way to do so?

EDIT:
I did not mean to ask overly specific, but I realize I was disturbing people here. So here's my specific problem. In fact I do have an example that works, but I don't consider it really nifty. Plus it has a shortcoming that I need to overcome: it does not work correctly with apply.

```
library(plyr)

# make the dataset more "realistic"
mydata <- warpbreaks
names(mydata) <- c("someValue","group","size")
mydata$category <- c(1,2,3)
mydata$categoryA <- c("A","A","X","X","Z","Z")
# add some NA
mydata$category[c(8,10,19)] <- NA
mydata$categoryA[c(14,1,20)] <- NA


# someValue is summarized !
# note we have a another, varying category hence we need the a parameter
calcShares <- function(a, data) {
# !is.na needs to be specific!
tempres1 <- eval(substitute(ddply(data[!is.na(a),],.(group,size,a),summarize,
                sumTest = sum(someValue,na.rm=T))),

                envir=data, enclos=parent.frame())
tempres2 <- eval(substitute(ddply(data[!is.na(a),],.(group,size),summarize,
                sumTestTotal = sum(someValue,na.rm=T))),
                envir=data, enclos=parent.frame())

res <- merge(tempres1,tempres2,by=c("group","size"))
res$share <- res$sumTest/res$sumTestTotal
 return(res)

}

test <- calcShares(category,mydata)
test2 <- calcShares(categoryA,mydata)   
head(test)
head(test2)
```

As you can see I intend to run this over different categorical variables. In the example I have only two (category, categoryA) but in fact I got more, so using apply with my function would be really nice, but somehow it does not work correctly.

```
applytest <- head(apply(mydata[grep("^cat",
             names(mydata),value=T)],2,calcShares,data=mydata))
```

.. returns a warning message and a strange name (newX[, i] ) for the category var.

So how can I do THIS a) more elegantly and b) fix the apply issue?

Comment: Nice Q. I always have done it with ddply wrapped in another ddply like you said, so I'm interested in a solution to this too. Will `table` + `prop.table` + `addmargins` work for you, or do you need the added flexibility of ddply?

Comment: Wouldn't you use the `count` function for that? My memory is that it's just a renaming of `length` which one needed to use with `ave` in base R.

Comment: Hmm. nice, did not know of prop.table, but I could still make use of ddply's flexibility though.

Comment: @DWin But what about when the total you want is something more than the small slice of, for example, grouplevel1:sizelevel1 that ddply has to work with at the moment? Like for this example we want the entire count of sizelevel1 in order to calculate the proportions. I think that's what ran2 wants, and to do this I've always had to do two passes of ddply, or more simply with the `table` family of functions.

Answer (score 3):

This seems simple, so I may be missing some aspect of your question.

First, define a function that calculates the values you want inside each level of `group`. Then, instead of using `.(group, size)` to split the data.frame, use `.(group)`, and apply the newly defined function to each of the split pieces.

```
library(plyr)

# Create a dataset with the names in your example
mydata <- warpbreaks
names(mydata) <- c("someValue", "group", "size")

# A function that calculates the proportional contribution of each size class 
# to the sum of someValue within a level of group
getProps <- function(df) {
    with(df, ave(someValue, size, FUN=sum)/sum(someValue))
}

# The call to ddply()
res <- ddply(mydata, .(group), 
             .fun = function(X) transform(X, PROPS=getProps(X)))

head(res, 12)
#    someValue group size     PROPS
# 1         26     A    L 0.4785203
# 2         30     A    L 0.4785203
# 3         54     A    L 0.4785203
# 4         25     A    L 0.4785203
# 5         70     A    L 0.4785203
# 6         52     A    L 0.4785203
# 7         51     A    L 0.4785203
# 8         26     A    L 0.4785203
# 9         67     A    L 0.4785203
# 10        18     A    M 0.2577566
# 11        21     A    M 0.2577566
# 12        29     A    M 0.2577566
```

Comment: +1 for bringing some fresh thoughts (with / ave / transform) to the table. I realized, I was a bit imprecise and posted a more specific reproducible example. What your solution lacks is the summary (i.e. aggregation). But maybe you can add this somehow to your solution. I am not focused on ddply only :)

Comment: I like this too, but I don't know if it's any simpler than just doing 2x ddply from the get go.