# Aggregate over categories that contain NAs with ddply and lapply?

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, lapply

I would like to aggregate a data.frame over 3 categories, with one of them varying. Unfortunately this one varying category contains NAs (actually it's the reason why it needs to vary). Thus I created a list of `data.frames`. Every data.frame within this list contains only complete cases with respect to three variables (with only one of them changing).

Let's reproduce this:

```
library(plyr)

mydata <- warpbreaks
names(mydata) <- c("someValue","group","size")
mydata$category <- c(1,2,3)
mydata$categoryA <- c("A","A","X","X","Z","Z")
# add some NA
mydata$category[c(8,10,19)] <- NA
mydata$categoryA[c(14,1,20)] <- NA 

# create a list of dfs that contains TRUE FALSE
noNAList <- function(vec){
res <- !is.na(vec)
return(res)
}

testTF <- lapply(mydata[,c("category","categoryA")],noNAList)

# create a list of data.frames
selectDF <- function(TFvec){
res <- mydata[TFvec,]
return(res)
}

# check x and see that it may contain NAs as long
# as it's not in one of the 3 categories I want to aggregate over    
x <-lapply(testTF,selectDF)

## let's ddply get to work
doddply <- function(df){
ddply(df,.(group,size),summarize,sumTest = sum(someValue))
}

y <- lapply(x, doddply);y
```

`y` comes very close to what I want to get

```
$category
group size sumTest
1     A    L     375
2     A    M     198
3     A    H     185
4     B    L     254
5     B    M     259
6     B    H     169

$categoryA
group size sumTest
1     A    L     375
2     A    M     204
3     A    H     200
4     B    L     254
5     B    M     259
6     B    H     169
```

But I need to implement aggregation over a third varying variable, which is in this case `category` and `categoryA`. Just like:

```
group size category sumTest sumTestTotal      
1      A    H        1      46          221 
2      A    H        2      46          221 
3      A    H        3      93          221
```

and so forth. How can I add names(x) to lapply, or do I need a loop or environment here?

EDIT:
Note that I want EITHER category OR categoryA added to the mix. In reality I have about 15 mutually exclusive categorical vars.

Comment: In some way this a follow-up question to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897927/how-can-i-use-ddply-with-varying-variables

Comment: `rm(list=ls())` is a pretty devious line to include in code that folks are likely to copy+paste into their session in an attempt to _help you_. ;)

Comment: On point joran, I hope it didn't crush this weeks work for you. removed it.

Comment: Why I NEVER do odd jobs in a working R session! Start a fresh R every time, kids!

Comment: I caught it in time. I'm laughing, not frowning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know the question explicitly requests a `ddply()/lapply()` solution.

But ... if you are willing to come on over to the dark side, here is a `data.table()`-based function that should do the trick:

```
# Convert mydata to a data.table
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(mydata, key = c("group", "size"))

# Define workhorse function
myfunction <- function(dt, VAR) {
    E <- as.name(substitute(VAR))
    dt[i = !is.na(eval(E)), 
       j = {n <- sum(.SD[,someValue]) 
            .SD[, list(sumTest = sum(someValue),
                       sumTestTotal = n,
                       share = sum(someValue)/n), 
                by = VAR]
           }, 
       by = key(dt)]
}

# Test it out
s1 <- myfunction(dt, "category")
s2 <- myfunction(dt, "categoryA")
```

**ADDED ON EDIT**

Here's how you could run this for a vector of different categorical variables:

```
catVars <- c("category", "categoryA")

ll <- lapply(catVars, 
             FUN = function(X) {
                       do.call(myfunction, list(dt, X))
                   })
names(ll) <- catVars

lapply(ll, head, 3)
# $category
#      group size category sumTest sumTestTotal     share
# [1,]     A    H        2      46          185 0.2486486
# [2,]     A    H        3      93          185 0.5027027
# [3,]     A    H        1      46          185 0.2486486
# 
# $categoryA
#      group size categoryA sumTest sumTestTotal share
# [1,]     A    H         A      79          200 0.395
# [2,]     A    H         X      68          200 0.340
# [3,]     A    H         Z      53          200 0.265
```

Comment: @ran2 -- If you think this would be better posted as a response to the question you asked earlier, just let me know, and I'll move it there. Cheers.

Comment: dark side... now we're talkin!

Comment: I'll check it, got an own solution in the making based list2env and eval and post it here if it works. Don't know about your suggestion (yet). At the moment I'd rather delete the first question and go on with this one, because I feel my explanation is better and so is the discussion. Thanks for the offer though, i will get back to you :)

Comment: impressive. But how to let it work through a category variables. Do not want to call 15 of them manually...

Comment: me neither. +1 for this anyway and you are likely to get the acc, too – if mine aint better with respect to running it over a vector of categorical vars :)

Comment: I just edited the function to take a character argument for the name of the categorical variable. That, in turn, makes it easier to use `lapply()` to produce summaries for each of the elements in a vector of categorical variables.

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing. This is really amazing. I have been chasing a solution for a while and finally learned something really interesting here. One last question :) Why is there a line of labels below when I print ll? Does it come from the data.table?

Comment: @ran2 -- Yep, that's a little courtesy performed by `print.data.table()`. If you print a data.table with more than 20 rows, it'll repeat the column names after the final line of the table.  Try `data.table(longnamehere=1:21)` vs. `data.table(longnamehere=1:21)` to see this in action.

Comment: Finally, got an (less elegant) alternative without data.table... thanks for your help, again.

Answer (score 4):

I think you might be making this really hard on yourself, if I understand your question correctly.

If you want to aggregate the data.frame 'myData' by three (or four) variables, you would simply do this:

```
aggregate(someValue ~ group + size + category + categoryA, sum, data=mydata)

   group size category categoryA someValue
1      A    L        1         A        51
2      B    L        1         A        19
3      A    M        1         A        17
4      B    M        1         A        63
```

`aggregate` will automatically remove rows that include `NA` in any of the categories. If someValue is sometimes `NA`, then you can add the parameter na.rm=T.

I also noted that you put a lot of unnecessary code into functions. For example:

```
# create a list of data.frames
selectDF <- function(TFvec){
    res <- mydata[TFvec,]
    return(res)
}
```

Can be written like:

```
selectDF <- function(TFvec) mydata[TFvec,]
```

Also, using `lapply` to create a list of two data frames without the `NA` is overkill. Try this code:

```
x = list(mydata[!is.na(mydata$category),],mydata[!is.na(mydata$categoryA),])
```

Comment: +1 for helping out with selectDF, did not think of that. Still, you miss something here: I have 2 fixed categorical variables and one varying variables. Your code takes care of 3 when 3 are available and of 4 when 4 are available. In the real dataset I have about 15 categorical variables in addition to the fixed ones. And I need an extra aggregation for every one of them. Edited the question to make this clear.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a solution that might not be as slick as Josh' but it works without no dark forces (data.table). You may laugh – here's my reproducible example using the same sample data as in the question.

```
qual <- c("category","categoryA")

# get T / F vectors
noNAList <- function(vec){
res <- !is.na(vec)
return(res)
}

selectDF <- function(TFvec) mydata[TFvec,]

NAcheck <- lapply(mydata[,qual],noNAList)

# create a list of data.frames
listOfDf <- lapply(NAcheck,selectDF)

workhorse <- function(charVec,listOfDf){
dfs <- list2env(listOfDf)
# create expression list
exlist <- list()
for(i in 1:length(qual)){
exlist[[qual[i]]] <- parse(text=paste("ddply(",qual[i],
                                  ",.(group,size,",qual[i],"),summarize,sumTest =    sum(someValue))",
                                  sep=""))
}

res <- lapply(exlist,eval,envir=dfs)
return(res)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this more like what you mean? I find your example extremely difficult to understand. In the below code, the method can take any column, and then aggregate by it. It can return multiple aggregation functions of someValue. I then find all the column names you would like to aggregate by, and then apply the function to that vector.

```
# Build a method to aggregate by column.
agg.by.col = function (column) {
    by.list=list(mydata$group,mydata$size,mydata[,column])
    names(by.list) = c('group','size',column)
    aggregate(mydata$someValue, by=by.list, function(x) c(sum=sum(x),mean=mean(x)))
}

# Find all the column names you want to aggregate by
cols = names(mydata)[!(names(mydata) %in% c('someValue','group','size'))]

# Apply the method to each column name.
lapply (cols, agg.by.col)
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time. If my example is not good, maybe Josh' example helps. Running his code does exactly what I want. It perfectly solves the question.